# How to handle negative numbers in CSS classes

Tags: css, naming-conventions

Assuming you have a default value of `0` and a scale that goes up and down some numbers like `-12` to `12` or so. How would you write each class for each value? Positive is simple (e.g. `.foo-bar-3` for `3`), but how the negative?

There are some options I came up with:

1. `.foo-bar--12` for `-12` with `-12`in class name
2. `.foo-bar-m12` for `-12` and `m` for **m**inus
3. `.foo-bar-12n` for `-12` with `n` suffix for **n**egative
4. `.foo-bar-n12` for `-12` with `n` prefix for **n**egative

Any ideas?

Comment: You answered yourself already I think.

Comment: Your first option is not ideal as it can be easily confused for a (positive) BEM modifier. 

But nothing wrong with the **m**inus or **n**egative approach.

Comment: 4. `.foo-bar-minus12` or `.foo-bar-minus-12` IMO

Comment: @felipeAls Do you say "negative 12" or "minus 12"?

Answer (score 1):

I rather use a name describing the purpose of the class and not its style. It is posible that later on you want to change your measurement, but the particular purpose of the class will probably remain the same. Also, you can “see” what the class its doing do just by looking at its values. So:

```
.this-do-this {property: value;}
.another-purpose {property: value;}
.negative-something {property: value;}
```

Just change the class name to describe what the class is doing instead of what specific measurement will be apply; the property/value pair will do that.

Comment: I know about this, but for my question's example, which is more like a utility class/helper, I want to know if there are better ways to express negative numbers in a class because of the issue with the minus (dash) also being a separator in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I you are really going to name classes base on its style instead of the its use (which its not recommend), then use the word “negative”. Most of the times is clear enough. Like .negative-margin-14px, .negative-indent-1em, etc.